# Combine fields from different rows on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Amazon offers their marketplace customers a CSV report which contains information about every article you sold. There are four rows per article, looking like this:

```
+----------------------+------------+-------------------+--------+
|       orderid        | amounttype | amountdescription | amount |
+----------------------+------------+-------------------+--------+
| 305-2406165-0572365  | ItemPrice  | Principal         | 2.98   |
| 305-2406165-0572365  | ItemPrice  | Shipping          | 3.89   |
| 305-2406165-0572365  | ItemFees   | Commission        | -0.45  |
| 305-2406165-0572365  | ItemFees   | ShippingHB        | -0.59  |
+----------------------+------------+-------------------+--------+
```

As you can see, every article has four rows, two for the actual selling price and two for the fees I have to pay to Amazon.

I import this CSV file into a SQL-table using MySQL. Selecting some data including the price looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    report.posteddate AS Date,
    orders.OrderID,
    orders.ExternalOrderID AS AZNr,
    report.amount AS ArtPrice
FROM
    report,
    orders
WHERE
    orders.ExternalOrderID = report.orderid
        AND report.amountdescription = 'Principal'
        AND report.transactiontype = 'Order'
ORDER by Date DESC
```

To get just the item price without the shipping I do a selection to get only the rows where amountdescription is "Principal". The transactiontype can be ignored in order to solve my problem.

What I want to do:

I want to extract both fields of amount where amounttype is "ItemFees", add them together and display the result as a single field. After this selection, a row should look like this:

```
+------------+---------+---------------------+----------+-------+
|    Date    | OrderID |        AZNr         | ArtPrice | Fees  |
+------------+---------+---------------------+----------+-------+
| 24.07.2014 |  267720 | 305-2406165-0572365 | 2.98     | -1.04 |
+------------+---------+---------------------+----------+-------+
```

I tried to run a subquery for both rows with a selection to amounttype = "ItemFees" and combine the results, but I ended up in an error saying that my subquery returns more than one row. This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    report.posteddate AS Date,
    orders.OrderID,
    orders.ExternalOrderID AS AZNr,
    report.amount AS ArtPrice,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(report.amount)
        FROM
            report,
            orders
        WHERE
            orders.ExternalOrderID = report.orderid
                AND report.amountdescription = 'Commission') +
    (SELECT 
            SUM(report.amount)
        FROM
            report,
            orders
        WHERE
            orders.ExternalOrderID = report.orderid
                AND report.amountdescription = 'ShippingHB') AS Fees
FROM
    report,
    orders
WHERE
    orders.ExternalOrderID = report.orderid
        AND report.amountdescription = 'Principal'
        AND report.transactiontype = 'Order'
ORDER by Date DESC
```

Does anybody have an idea how to sum up two values from two different rows with the given condition (see WHERE-clause)? Also, I need to extract the shipping value, but I think this is the same question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you use a SUM(amount) in your subquery?

Comment: Yes I did, but I just got a thousand fields that contained the same value.

Comment: Can you update your question with the complete SQL query that didn't work, including the subquery that give you thousands of fields?

Comment: @Ian Added, forgot when I wrote the question.

Comment: I've never tried using a subquery in the field list of a SELECT statement that used other fields that are filtered later.  So I would suggest moving your subqueries into the FROM section and doing a JOIN...as @1010 suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can calculate itemprice and itemfees with two queries and join them

```
select a.orderid, a.price, b.fees
from (select orderid, sum(amount) price from report where amounttype='ItemPrice' group by orderid) a
     join (select orderid, sum(amount) fees from report where amounttype='ItemFees' group by orderid) b
     on a.orderid = b.orderid
```

this asumes there is at least one row with itemprice and one row with itemfees. otherwise you should use an outer join.

Comment: Thank you, summing up the fees works! But there is a problem with the price: With your query, the calculated price contains the shipping, but I want to write it in an own field. How can I extract it with your JOIN-query? I already excluded it from the calculated price, but I have trouble to get it in its own field. Other thing: In my table 'orders' is another OrderID which needs to get extracted too (see my first query). I tried to just add 'orders' to the FROM-clause, but I don't know how to create the selection I did with orders.ExternalOrderID = report.orderid in my first query.

Comment: couldn't answer before. I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: @Ceriana to add the shipping price to this query you just have to add a join with report. if there's only one shipping per orderid you don't have to sum it with a subquery.