# Confused by JOINs - data missing in result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This thread is related with my older one [Combine fields from different rows on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951728/combine-fields-from-different-rows-on-condition).

I adjusted the query I got from this thread to meet some other requirements.

```
SELECT 
    a.Date,
    a.orderid AS AZNr,
    a.Typ,
    ROUND(a.Fees, 2) AS Fees,
    ROUND(b.Shipping, 2) AS Shipping,
    ROUND(c.Price, 2) AS Price,
    d.DeliveryLand
FROM
    (SELECT 
        posteddate AS Date,
            transactiontype AS Typ,
            orderid,
            SUM(amount) AS Fees
    FROM
        report
    WHERE
        amounttype = 'ItemFees'
    GROUP BY orderid) a
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        orderid, SUM(amount) AS Shipping
    FROM
        report
    WHERE
        amountdescription = 'Shipping'
    GROUP BY orderid) b ON a.orderid = b.orderid
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        orderid, SUM(amount) AS Price
    FROM
        report
    WHERE
        amountdescription = 'Principal'
    GROUP BY orderid) c ON b.orderid = c.orderid
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        DeliveryLand, ExternalOrderId
    FROM
        orders) d ON c.orderid = d.ExternalOrderId
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

I had to do a `LEFT JOIN` on the last table to get the DeliveryLand, but not every item from the report-table has one entry in the orders-table.

After I did some calculating I found that this query does not return all entries. There should be 25 entries with "typ" = "Refund", but I only get 20 of them. Some orders might contain entries that other orders (identified by orderid) might not have.

I did another query to sum up the fees, the shipping costs and the price just for the refunds:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(ROUND(a.Fees, 2)) AS Fees,
    SUM(ROUND(b.Shipping, 2)) AS Shipping,
    SUM(ROUND(c.Price, 2)) AS Price
FROM
    (SELECT 
        orderid, SUM(amount) AS Fees
    FROM
        report
    WHERE
        amounttype = 'ItemFees'
            AND transactiontype = 'Refund'
    GROUP BY orderid) a
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        orderid, SUM(amount) AS Shipping
    FROM
        report
    WHERE
        amountdescription = 'Shipping'
            AND transactiontype = 'Refund'
    GROUP BY orderid) b ON a.orderid = b.orderid
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        orderid, SUM(amount) AS Price
    FROM
        report
    WHERE
        amountdescription = 'Principal'
            AND transactiontype = 'Refund'
    GROUP BY orderid) c ON b.orderid = c.orderid
```

The first two results, fees and shipping costs, are summed up correctly (I got the original data for comparison), but the last one, the price, isn't correct, its too much. I guess there is some data getting truncated by the `LEFT JOIN`, but I can't figure out why and where, especially this query works perfectly fine when I sum up the same colums for "transactiontype" = "Order".

I don't know why there is some data truncated or missing. Can somebody help me with these confusing JOINs I do in both queries? If you need more information, please ask.

Thank you in advance!

€dited query:

```
  SELECT 
    posteddate AS Date,
    transactiontype AS Typ,
    report.orderid AS AZNr,
    ROUND(SUM((amounttype = 'ItemFees') * amount),
            2) AS Fees,
    ROUND(SUM((amountdescription = 'Shipping') * amount),
            2) AS Shipping,
    ROUND(SUM((amountdescription = 'Principal') * amount),
            2) AS Price,
    orders.DeliveryLand,
    articles.ItemVAT AS VAT
FROM
    report
        LEFT JOIN
    orders ON report.orderid = orders.ExternalOrderID
        LEFT JOIN
    articles ON report.sku = articles.ItemID
GROUP BY report.orderid , transactiontype
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by simplifying the query, it can be written without `JOIN`s. I'd also question why you `ROUND` before the `SUM` which will take longer and be less precise.

I'd do:

```
  SELECT orderid,
         ROUND(SUM((amountdescription='ItemFees')*amount), 2)) AS Fees,
         ROUND(SUM((amountdescription='Shipping')*amount), 2)) AS Shipping,
         ROUND(SUM((amountdescription='Principal')*amount), 2)) AS Price
    FROM report
   WHERE transactiontype='Refund'
GROUP BY orderid
```

As an explanation `(amountdescription='ItemFees')` returns 1 if true and 0 if not, thus the amounts are only summed that match each condition specified.. you can use the longer `CASE` if you prefer:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN *condition* THEN amount ELSE 0 END)
```

You may be losing some data from the original query as it relies on all the subtables linking up.. if there are no `Fees` then an order's `Shipping` and `Price` would not have been returned.

**UPDATE**

Don't forget if you have two transactiontypes on the same orderid, they will all count as the same order and will both be included in the same sum.. to get the transaction types separately use:

```
  SELECT orderid, transactiontype,
         ROUND(SUM((amountdescription='ItemFees')*amount), 2)) AS Fees,
         ROUND(SUM((amountdescription='Shipping')*amount), 2)) AS Shipping,
         ROUND(SUM((amountdescription='Principal')*amount), 2)) AS Price
    FROM report
GROUP BY orderid, transactiontype
```

Comment: I tried your query. With the selection for transactiontype='Refund' I get all the desired 25 rows. But when I select all rows without selecting a special transactiontype, I only get 20 rows with Refunds, the rest gets truncated. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: That shouldn't be possible.. you can't reduce the result set by removing the WHERE. Did you change the WHERE instead? Are some of your rows returning NULL but are actually there?

Comment: Yes, there are some rows that don't contain a Shipping. Thats why I tried the LEFT JOIN. These missing fields result in a "0.00", but when selected without the transactiontype, they get truncated.

Comment: @Ceriana Yep, but you were using the orderid from the empty Shipping table (b.orderid) to join to the Price table (c.orderid) which will result in no Price rows being picked up. Not using any JOINs will solve this..  Did my update clear anything up?

Comment: Yep, your updated helped, I get all existing rows. Thank you so far!

But something is missing. As you can see in my first posted query, I need to extract the "DeliveryLand" from the table `orders`. Because not every entry (identified by report.orderid = orders.ExternalOrderID) has a DeliveryLand specified, I used there a LEFT JOIN, too. Of course I got all missing fields filled up with NULL. Also, I need to extract another piece of data from another table for which not every rows has a value, too. I tried adding LEFT JOIN in both cases, but this query runs for ages. See my edit for the query.

Comment: As long as you only have one row in each of the other tables for each orderid you should be ok.. and it looks like you've done it right (although I'd add the other non-sum rows to the GROUP BY). If not you're gonna get into a world of trouble with all the extra rows affecting your SUMs. You'll have to look at your indexing to speed it up, but this really belongs in another question.

Comment: Thank you very much, Arth. I installed the new query into my application, and everything is working as intended.