# Summing up fields from different rows in MySQL - small but significant error

Tags: mysql

This topic is related to the query I asked for in this topic

[Combine fields from different rows on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951728/combine-fields-from-different-rows-on-condition)

with its continuation

[Confused by JOINs - data missing in result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128296/confused-by-joins-data-missing-in-result)

The query sums up all values from amount if the amounttype in the rows is ItemFees, Promotion or Shipping (description).
The query described (see the linked article for detailed description):

```
SELECT
    posteddate AS Date,
    transactiontype AS Type,
    report.orderid AS OrderID,
    ROUND(SUM((amounttype = 'ItemFees') * amount),
        2) AS Fees,
    ROUND(SUM((amounttype = 'Promotion') * amount),
        2) AS Promo,
ROUND(SUM((amountdescription = 'Shipping') * amount),
        2) AS Shipping,
    ROUND(SUM((amountdescription = 'Principal' AND amounttype = 'ItemPrice') *amount),
            2) AS Price,
    orders.DeliveryLand AS Country,
    items.ItemVAT AS VAT
FROM
    report
        LEFT JOIN
    ordersON report.orderid = orders.ExternalOrderID
        LEFT JOIN
    items ON report.sku = items.ItemID
WHERE DeliveryLand = 1
GROUP BY report.orderid , transactiontype
ORDER BY Date DESC, OrderID ASC;
```

This query works as intended - in most cases. But lets take these entries as a example:

```
+-----------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+--------+
| transactiontype | orderid             | amounttype | amountdescription | amount |
+-----------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+--------+
| Order           | 305-2406165-0572365 | ItemPrice  | Principal         | 23.24  |
| Order           | 305-2406165-0572365 | ItemPrice  | Shipping          | 3.69   |
| Order           | 305-2406165-0572365 | ItemFees   | Commission        | -3.49  |
| Order           | 305-2406165-0572365 | ItemFees   | ShippingHB        | -0.55  |
| Refund          | 305-2406165-0572365 | ItemPrice  | Principal         | -23.24 |
| Refund          | 305-2406165-0572365 | ItemPrice  | Shipping          | -3.69  |
| Refund          | 305-2406165-0572365 | ItemFees   | Commission        | 3.49   |
| Refund          | 305-2406165-0572365 | ItemFees   | ShippingHB        | 0.55   |
+-----------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+--------+
```

As you can see, the customer bought an article, but requested a refund. Unfortunately, both actions are identified by the same orderid, but they need to be seperated (I need to list orders and refunds separate). So, the query does exactly what it is told to do, and gives me this output:

```
+------------+--------+---------------------+-------+-------+----------+
| date       | type   | orderid             | fees  | promo | shipping | price | country | VAT
+------------+--------+---------------------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---+---+
| 1419375600 | Refund | 305-2406165-0572365 | 8,08  |     0 | -7,38 | -46,48 | 1 | 0 |
+------------+--------+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+--------+---+---+
| 1419375600 | Order  | 305-2406165-0572365 | -8,08 |     0 | 7,38  | 46,48  | 1 | 0 |
+------------+--------+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+--------+---+---+
```

Now, if you do the math, you can see that all values are multiplied by two. I can't figure out why the query does this, and how to fix this. I need all actions separate, first identified by the `orderid`, but then distinguished by the transactiontype. Any ideas on this?

Correct would be:

```
+------------+--------+---------------------+-------+-------+----------+
| date       | type   | orderid             | fees  | promo | shipping | price | country | VAT
+------------+--------+---------------------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---+---+
| 1419375600 | Refund | 305-2406165-0572365 | 4,04  |     0 | -3,69 | -23,24 | 1 | 0 |
+------------+--------+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+--------+---+---+
| 1419375600 | Order  | 305-2406165-0572365 | -4,04 |     0 | 3,69  | 23,24  | 1 | 0 |
+------------+--------+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+--------+---+---+
```

Then, another thing that happened while I wrote this question:

There is another order (without refund) that contained the exact same values as the one above. Unless it has a different orderid, it is still listed with the wrong doubles values! Confused by that, I hope anyone knows an answer.

I hope I gave enough information about the problem. If not, feel free to request any information you need.

Comment: For clarity, can you provide the correct output, just below the incorrect one

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I added the correct output.

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what the underlying data looks like in each of your 3 tables.  It sounds like a Cartesian product issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute this bit first:

```
SELECT x.transactiontype 
     , x.orderid 
     , ROUND(SUM((amounttype = 'ItemFees') * amount),2) Fees
     , ROUND(SUM((amounttype = 'Promotion') * amount),2) Promo
     , ROUND(SUM((amountdescription = 'Shipping') * amount),2) Shipping
     , ROUND(SUM((amountdescription = 'Principal' AND amounttype = 'ItemPrice') * amount),2) Price
  FROM report x
 GROUP 
    BY transactiontype
     , orderid
```

and then join that as a subquery onto the rest of the query